# Charlieplexing ledstrips together

Tags: mosfet, led-strip, charlieplexing

I know there is a lot of charlieplexing tutorials out there but non of them are very suitable for my case. I want to charlieplex 4 ledstrips together and control them by an arduino. This means that i need a seperate powersupply and use some mosfets to control the inputs. However I can't think of a way to implement that in my current scheme. I'm very new to all this so I could just not know something that is possible so that's why I'm asking here.
[image: Schematic]

Does anyone know a way to do this?
Thanks in advance,
Stijn

Comment: that sure is a messy schematic ... very annoying ... why do you need to use charlieplexing?  ... you have more than enough pins on the controller chip.

Comment: Charlie plexing is unlikely to work with more than single bare diodes based on the voltage required alone.

Comment: You do realize you are using 4 outputs to control 4 strips right? If this is for educational purposes you should be trying single LEDs with resistors.

Comment: Well, on the arduino mega there are 13pwm pins and each led strip will use 3 pins, so 3*4=12 pins. And I also need some pins for other stuff that will be attached to it.

Comment: @Passerby I'm sorry but what exactly do you mean? The external powersupply is 12V and 12A that should be enough right?

Comment: You cannot directly drive LED strips with the pins. (Unless they are 5V and no more than a few tens of mA)

Comment: The Atmega is a 5V microcontroller and you have power for your strips both going and coming from the microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Charlieplexing relies on the ability of a microcontroller to drive its pins high, low or tristate. In order to do the same thing at 12V, you'll need a bunch of half-bridge drivers, each controlled by two pins on the µC.

It also requires the LEDs (strips, in your case) to be able to withstand the supply voltage applied in reverse, something that single LEDs can easily do at 5V or less. You'll probably have to add a silicon diode in series with each of your strips.

Answer (score 0):

A deleted answer had a very clever idea. @syd suggested using opto-isolators. The transistor side of the op to would be used to drive the transistor or mosfets needed for the led strips, while the led side of the opto would be driven like a normal charlie-plex circuit would be.

Absolutely no reason the led in an opto can't be charlie-plex like any other led.

The only concern with that is ensuring the voltage and current requirements for the optos, as well as the speed that you need to switch the circuit for proper light output at your strips. This is a unique idea but requires testing.